# DirectX writing backbuffer data to file

Tags: directx, textures, staging

I am trying to convert every frame of my DirectX program to YUV (for video encoding). Therefore I need the RGB(A) values of each pixel on every frame first. I need to get these from the backbuffer.

Because there is no glReadPixels in DirectX, I do the following:

1. Get pointer to the backbuffer's renderTargetView and get the backbuffer resource
2. Cast this resource to `ID3D10Texture2D`
3. Make a staging texture and `CopyResource` the texture2D from the previous step.

At this point I can use `D3DX10SaveTextureToFile` and this staging texture will correctly save the backbuffer as an image.

However, I don't want to use the disk as a detour, I want to get the RGB data right away, so I do the following:

1. Map the staging resource
2. Read the pData of the mapped texture to get the RGB(A) values

The problem: the RGB values are rubbish. This is an example for pixel (1,1)

> (1, 1) = (-170141183460469230000000000000000000000.000000,
>   -170141183460469230000000000000000000000.000000, -170141183460469230000000000000000000000.000000)

This is particularly strange because I use the same code to Map another staging texture (from another offscreen render target) and this code works just fine there.

This is my code:

```
// Get resource pointer to backbuffer
ID3D10Resource *backbufferRes;
m_D3D->GetRenderTargetView()->GetResource(&backbufferRes);

// Cast backbuffer resource to texture2D
ID3D10Texture2D* tempTexture = 0;
backbufferRes->QueryInterface(__uuidof(ID3D10Texture2D),(LPVOID*) &tempTexture);
backbufferRes->Release();

// Get the descriptor of this texture2D
D3D10_TEXTURE2D_DESC descDefault; 
tempTexture->GetDesc(&descDefault);

// Create a staging texture desc based on the texture of the backbuffer
D3D10_TEXTURE2D_DESC descStaging;
descStaging = descDefault;
descStaging.Usage = D3D10_USAGE_STAGING;
descStaging.CPUAccessFlags = D3D10_CPU_ACCESS_READ;  
descStaging.BindFlags = 0;

// Create the new empty staging texture
ID3D10Texture2D *texture = 0;
m_D3D->GetDevice()->CreateTexture2D( &descStaging, NULL, &texture);

// Copy the backbuffer texture data (tempTexture) to the staging texture (texture)
m_D3D->GetDevice()->CopyResource(texture, tempTexture);

// This call works perfectly, image is correct!
// D3DX10SaveTextureToFile(texture, D3DX10_IFF_BMP, L"D:\\img.bmp");

// We want to avoid disk access, so instead let's map the texture and read its RGB data
D3D10_MAPPED_TEXTURE2D mappedTexture;
hr = texture->Map(D3D10CalcSubresource(0, 0, 1), D3D10_MAP_READ, 0, &mappedTexture);
FLOAT* m_pBits = (FLOAT*) malloc(4 * descStaging.Width * descStaging.Height * sizeof(FLOAT));
if(!FAILED(hr)) {
    memcpy(m_pBits, mappedTexture.pData, 4 * descStaging.Width * descStaging.Height);
    texture->Unmap(D3D10CalcSubresource(0, 0, 1));
}
texture->Release();
tempTexture->Release();

fp = fopen("D:\\output.txt", "a");
for( UINT row = 0; row < descStaging.Height; row++ )
{
    UINT rowStart = row * mappedTexture.RowPitch / 4;
    for( UINT col = 0; col < descStaging.Width; col++ )
    {
        r = m_pBits[rowStart + col*4 + 0]; // Red (X)
        g = m_pBits[rowStart + col*4 + 1]; // Green (Y)
        b = m_pBits[rowStart + col*4 + 2]; // Blue (Z)
        a = m_pBits[rowStart + col*4 + 3]; // Alpha (W)

        // Save pixel values to disk
        fprintf(fp, "%d %d - %f %f %f\n",  col + 1, row + 1, r, g, b);
    }
}
fclose(fp);
```

Does anyone have an idea on what the problem might be? 
All help is really appreciated.

Comment: How about rendering your frame to a texture as a rendertarget and postprocess it with a rgb to yuv shader? That would be much faster then a manual conversion, because of the parallel capabilities of the gpu.

Comment: Thanks! This is actually a great idea, I'll try it out. Rendering to a texture was an alternative I had in mind (it fixes the issue at the cost of another render pass), but I'm still wondering why I get those results.

Answer (score 2):

Old question, but I think this might be the problem:

After you map the texture with `texture->Map()`, you try to copy it across into `m_pBits` all in one go. This won't work unless the RowPitch of the mapped texture is the same as its width (see [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb205319(v=vs.85).aspx)).

Instead, you must copy across the image row-by-row:

```
BYTE* source = static_cast<BYTE*>(mappedTexture.pData);
BYTE& dest = m_pBits;
for (int i = 0; i < IMAGE_HEIGHT; ++i) {
    memcpy(dest, source, IMAGE_WIDTH * 4); // for 4 bytes per pixel
    source += mappedTexture.RowPitch;
    dest += IMAGE_WIDTH * 4;
}
```